# Why is what timers show so counter-intuitive?

Tags: performance, rust

I am making a parser of some text. I need to support unicode texts, that's why I am using the `String::chars` iterator:

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=384b5b4c8c5d570aa5623b34768b91f3)

```rust
use std::time::Instant;

fn main() {
    let text = "a".repeat(10000);
    let mut timer1 = 0;
    let mut timer2 = 0;

    let start1 = Instant::now();
    for pos in 1..10000 {
        let start2 = Instant::now();
        let ch = text.chars().nth(pos).unwrap();
        timer2 += start2.elapsed().as_millis();
    }
    timer1 += start1.elapsed().as_millis();

    println!("timer1: {} timer2: {}", timer1, timer2);
}
```

Example output:

```
timer1: 4276 timer2: 133
```

Why is `timer2` unbelievably less than `timer1`, when I believe they should be very close to each other?

P.S. I know already that `.nth` is slow, and shouldn't be used.

Comment: Each loop iteration is going to run in much less than a millisecond (when doing `.chars().enumerate()`). `as_millis` returns an integer, so anything less than a millisecond is rounded to 0. Try to use `as_nanos` instead...

Comment: @kazemakase Oh my god. You are correct. I had many other things to think about so I couldn't see this simple reason.... Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are running into a resolution problem. The inside of the loop takes (on average) less than one millisecond to execute, so `start2.elapsed().as_millis()` usually evaluates to 0. To fix this problem, you could do some operation inside the loop that takes even longer, or change your resolution from milliseconds to something smaller, like microseconds or nanoseconds.

switching to microseconds yields a more consistent time

```rust
use std::time::{Instant};

fn main() {
    let text = "a".repeat(10000);
    let mut timer1 = 0;
    let mut timer2 = 0;

    let start1 = Instant::now();
    for pos in 1..10000 {
        let start2 = Instant::now();
        let ch = text.chars().nth(pos).unwrap();
        timer2+=start2.elapsed().as_micros();
    }
    timer1+=start1.elapsed().as_micros();

    println!("timer1: {} timer2: {}", timer1, timer2);
}
```

output

```
timer1: 3511812 timer2: 3499669
```

This question was tagged performance, so I'd like to point out that using `std::Instant` is a very tedious way to measure performance. Better ways include [criterion.rs](https://github.com/bheisler/criterion.rs), [flamegraph](https://github.com/ferrous-systems/flamegraph) and [cargo-bench](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.16.0/book/benchmark-tests.html).

Comment: For a moment I thought that this answer is a low-effort stealing, but you know what, those links you appended are incredibly useful to a Rust beginner like me! Thank you!

Comment: I apologize to the commenter who said the same thing as me, but I didn't see their comment while writing this. If they had posted an answer instead, I would have gotten a notification, and known.

Comment: I posted a comment because I did not have the time to phrase out a proper answer. Since someone else took that time it's only fair they receive the praise and upvotes. Here, have mine :)