# How to skip n items from inside of an iterator loop?

Tags: rust, iterator

This code:

[play](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b839fbcbc215a3c9dc0c38c6b476ce80)

```
fn main() {
    let text = "abcd";

    for char in text.chars() {
        if char == 'b' {
            // skip 2 chars
        }
        print!("{}", char);
    }
    // prints `abcd`, but I want `ad`
}
```

prints `abcd`, but I want to skip 2 chars if `b` was found, so that it prints `ad`. How do I do that?

I tried to put the iterator into a variable outside the loop and manipulate that iterator within the loop, but the Borrow Checker doesn't allow that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

AFAIK you can't do that with a `for` loop. You will need to desugar it by hand:

```rust
let mut it = text.chars();
while let Some(char) = it.next() {
    if char == 'b' {
        it.nth(1); // nth(1) skips/consumes exactly 2 items
        continue;
    }
    print!("{}", char);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7873372f2ef21df4d68daaba9c0cff1d)

Comment: What If I want to skip, say 50 chars? Calling `.next` 50 times is neither nice nor fast. I tried modifying your example by replacing the second `.next` with `.skip` but that doesn't work.

Comment: My bad! Your answer is (almost) correct! I've edited it slightly so that it better matches my case.

Comment: Remember that "calling 50 times" applies only to people, especially when we are talking about iterator api, which is highly optimizable and LLVM tears apart repetetive tasks like these with ease. Unless you generated and looked at ASM yourself, you can't really claim that it happens "50 times", your cpu would increment-check 50 times either way, the call will most likely be elided.

Comment: @Sahsahae You are so wrong... See for example this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59044638/why-is-what-timers-show-so-counter-intuitive/59045092#59045092 where simple `.nth` shows how incredibly slow it may become.

Comment: What you linked is completely different so it in no way makes me wrong, there you iterate from beginning N times, I'm talking about iter().next() on same iterator, besides, if you're writing a parser by hand, you probably should be using `.next()` manually in any case, so it completely removes the issue.

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev please avoid change code without permission specially if you forget to update playground link - -

Answer (score 3):

If you want to keep an iterator style, you can use [`std::iter::successors`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/fn.successors.html) (I've replaced the special char with `'!'` for being more readable:

```
fn my_iter<'a>(s: &'a str) -> impl Iterator<Item = char> + 'a {
    let mut it = s.chars();

    std::iter::successors(it.next(), move |c| {
        if *c == '!' {
            it.next().and_then(|_| it.next())
        } else {
            it.next()
        }
    })
    .filter(|c| *c != '!')
}

fn main() {
    assert!(my_iter("a!bc").eq("ac".chars()));
    assert!(my_iter("!abcd").eq("bcd".chars()));
    assert!(my_iter("abc!d").eq("abc".chars()));
    assert!(my_iter("abcd!").eq("abcd".chars()));
}
```

Comment: Very interesting! However I find it less readable personally (yes I have a procedural, not functional brain)

Comment: This doesn't work with two consecutive sequence with `!` and why filter ?

Comment: @Stargateur Try to remove it…

Comment: from_fn make more sense so: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=662c27f686555e1be4a9c720f319c7b7

Comment: @Stargateur You better write it like that: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2499e7baed5753d27a1203dfeb57c85e